# How to reference 2D array of characters by reference in C

Tags: c, arrays, reference, char

I am trying to create a `2D array` of `chars` in **C** then pass a `pointer` of that to a different `function` which will assign a single `char` to the first spot in each row of the `arrays`... I keep getting different `errors`, here is a bit of the code.  Also all assignments must be done by pointer arithmetic, not using `rows[0][0]`

```
char(*rows)[size] = malloc(sizeof(*rows) * size);
otherFunction(seed, size, &rows);
}

void otherFunction(int seed, int size, char (**rows)[]) {
int count = 0;
while (count < (size*size)) {
    (&&rows + count) = 'X';
    count += size;
}
```

I know this is wrong but I'm not sure how to correct it

**edit**
using your suggestions I have revised the code, but it is still not right, I have added in my attempt at printing it out, I want it printed in order from row to row

```
char test[size][size];
makeTest(seed, size, &test);
displayTest(size, &test);
}

void makeTest(int seed, int size, char (*test)[size][size]) {
    int count = 0;
        while (count < (size*size)) {
    *(&test + count) = 'X';
        count += size;
    }
}

void displaytest(int size, char(*test)[size][size]) {
    for (int row = 0; row < (size*size); row += size) {
            for (int count = 0; count < size; count++) {
                printf("%c", *(test + row + count));
            }
             printf("\n");
         }
}
```

in the line of makeTest that assigns in X i get
 warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
in display test where i print the char i get 
warning: format â%câ expects type âintâ, but argument 2 has type âchar (*)[(long unsigned int)(size)]â

**final edit**
before I got an answer here that helped me enough, I managed to find one that worked somewhat on my own, i'm going to post it here in case it helps anyone else as well

```
char test[size][size];
generateTest(seed, size, *test);
displayTest(size, *test);
}

void generateTest(int seed, int size, char *test) {
for (int row = 1; row < size - 1; row += 1) {
    for (int column = 0; column < size; column++) {
        *(test + (row * size) + column) = 'X';
        }
    }
}
```

while the bounds are screwey thats b/c certain rows are covered in other loops, but this is roughly how I did it

Comment: The different approaches given in different answers aren't necessarily compatible with each other... you might have problems trying to mix them together.  Try sticking to one approach.  I think a review of pointers and arrays, or more practice, would help you as well -- you seem to be losing track of your data types sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void makeTest(int seed, int size, char (*test)[size][size]) {
    int count = 0;
    while (count < (size*size)) {
        *((char*)test + count) = 'X';
        count += size;
    }
}

void displayTest(int size, char(*test)[size][size]) {
    for (int row = 0; row < size*size; row+=size) {
        for (int count = 0; count < size; count++) {
            printf("%c", *((char*)test + row +count));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    int size = 5;
    int seed = 1;
    char test[size][size];
    memset(test, '?', sizeof(test));
    makeTest(seed, size, &test);
    displayTest(size, &test);
}
```

Comment: Yours appears to answer my question perfectly, naturally I had just managed to fumble my way into a working answer as well

Answer (score 0):

Why not use pointers to pointers instead of mixing in arrays?

```
char **rows = malloc(sizeof(char *) * size);
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++)
    rows[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);

/* Now `rows` can be used as a "2d array", or a matrix of size `size` x `size` */

otherFunction(seed, size, rows);

...

void otherFunction(int seed, int size, char **rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        {
            rows[i][j] = 'X';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It always helps me to have example code in a situation where I don't understand something, so I'll start by posting an example of what I would do. I'll leave it as an exercise for you to modify it to do whatever you need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRLEN_PLUS_NULL( s ) ( strlen( s ) + 1 )
#define AMOUNT 10
#define LENGTH 80

char ** CreateArrayOfStrings( int amount, int length )
{
    int i = 0;
    char ** stringArray = malloc( sizeof( char * ) * amount );

    if ( !stringArray )
    {
        perror( "Malloc" );
        return NULL;
    }

    for ( ; i < amount; ++i )
    {
        if ( !( stringArray[i] = malloc( length ) ) )
        {
            perror( "Malloc" );

            for ( --i; i >= 0; --i )
                free( stringArray[i] );
            free( stringArray );

            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return stringArray;
}

void FreeArrayOfStrings( char ** strings, int amount )
{
    int i = 0;

    for ( ; i < amount; ++i )
        free( strings[i] );

    return;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char ** myStrings = CreateArrayOfStrings( AMOUNT, LENGTH );

    if ( !myStrings ) return 1;

    for ( ; i < AMOUNT; ++i )
        memcpy( myStrings[i], "X", STRLEN_PLUS_NULL( "X" ) );
    for ( i = 0; i < AMOUNT; ++i )
        printf( "%s\n", myStrings[i] );

    FreeArrayOfStrings( myStrings, AMOUNT );
    free( myStrings );
    return 0;
}
```

Let's go through my `CreateArrayOfStrings()` function, first I create a set of character pointers in memory, with the number determined by the amount parameter. Then I test it to see if it was allocated or if `malloc()` returned an error(**always check for errors on `malloc()` calls**). After that, I loop through my newly created array of function pointers and set  each to point to length bytes in memory. If there is an error while allocating that memory, I reverse iterate through my array and return null.

In my main function, I set a `char **` variable named myStrings to the return value of `CreateArrayOfStrings()`. I test it to make sure there were no errors. Then proceed to loop through the array again, setting each character pointer's memory that was allocated previously to the string literal I specified in `memcpy()`. After that I print the result and cleanup my resources.

Again, I didn't use pointer notation in my code, but it would be a trivial change. You should probably figure out how to use array notation first, once you know that, you can try to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a `char *` to the beginning of the 2D array (and changing `otherFunction()` accordingly).

So, change the call to:

```
otherFunction(seed, size, rows[0]);
```

and `otherFunction()` to:

```
void otherFunction(int seed, int size, char *rows) {
    int count = 0;
    while (count < (size*size)) {
        *(rows + count) = 'X';
        count += size;
    }
}
```

With C99 you could also pass the 2D array as a 2D array (or a pointer to 1D array), using `size` to get the dimensions.  In this case, the call can be:

```
otherFunction(seed, size, rows);
```

...and `otherFunction()` can be simplified to:

```
void otherFunction(int seed, int size, char (*rows)[size]) {
    int count;
    for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
        rows[i][0] = 'X';
}
```

Although that uses the `[]` operator, if the reason you wanted to use pointer arithmetic instead was to allow different array dimensions then that should still be okay in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Well no need to panic
You could simply pass arguments by reference :

```
void main()
{char ch[3][3];
 .
 .
 func(&ch);
 .
}

void func(char *ch[3][3])
{.
 .
 //use it here as you want
 .
}
```

Comment: That seems to fix one of my initial problems, any chance you have any advice on how to use pointer aritmatic to assign a char to the first and last spot on each row (currently I'm just trying to get the first in my code) then print it all out again